# RUTA: Multiline Annotation

Tags: ruta

Full disclosure:  New to `RUTA`.

I have a multi line using regex to find the entity.  But I need it now to have the break removed in the annotation.

My `RUTA` looks like `"(?i)\\b[A-Z]{2}[[0-9]{1,}[\n]{0,}[0-9]{1,}]{1,}" -> EntitType;`

My results end up like

```
S01234
25475
```

How can I get it be `S0123425475`?

Comment: So you want to change the structure of the input text with `Ruta` (i.e., the break between the rows should be removed), right? 
A break in the input text will be represented as break in the CAS (ruta output). Therefore, with `Ruta` you cannot change the input structure.
You should either change the input text, or create first, separate annotations for each row and merge the covered text of both in a container annotation.

Comment: As the previous comment correctly states, you normaly cannot change the text in a CAS. However, you can chnage the value of a string feature of an annotation. You could set the covered text as a feature value and replace all line breaks.

Comment: Thank you both.  I have to admit I am not knowledgeable enough on how to achieve that.  Do you have any references or examples that I can get an idea from?  I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for storing a modified string in a feature:

```
DECLARE EntitType (String normalized);
e:EntitType{-> e.normalized = replaceAll(e.ct, "\n", "")};
```

DISCLAIMER: I am a developer of UIMA Ruta